# Let X be a random variable with a Poisson distribution, such that P(X > 2) = 0.3. Find P (X < 2).

Tags: poisson-distribution

The question is:

> Let X be a random variable with a Poisson distribution, such that P(X > 2) = 0.3. Find P (X < 2).

So, my workings so far are in line with the answer booklet but then the booklet goes;

$$e^{-\lambda}[1+\lambda + \frac{\lambda^2}{2} ] = 0.7\ gives\ \lambda =1.9138...  $$

So I'm just wondering how it got from the first section of the equation (which I got) to finding the value of lambda. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you understand how he reached this equation $e^{-\lambda}[1+\lambda + \frac{\lambda^2}{2} ] = 0.7$ right?

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj No, I understood how he reached that bit. I just don't understand how he then went on to find the value of lambda, since the booklet doesn't explain that.

Comment: Try finding the roots of the function $e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda+\frac{1}{2}{\lambda}^2)-0.7$ by graphing it.